# AWS RDS snapshot restore from west to east

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, snapshot

have query related to snapshot  restore .
my rds snasphot are copied everday from west to east region everyday after automated daily rds backups task gets completed. However

however last one month snasphot dint get copied to east region as there was limit of 100 snapshot in east which got crossed. No snapshot were copied for last 30 days.

Today(june13th) i had restore activity in dr region from latest snapshot copied from west. So we taken latest snapshot from west manually and copied to east region. Our query is that will the latest snapshot copied from west to east is enough to restore rds sql in east? Any impact of earlier snapshots missing of last 30days which dint get copied into east region ?

appreciate any guidance on this

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are fine.

Every snapshot contains all information required to restore the Amazon RDS instance.

You can think of them as "full backups", but they are actually slightly more intelligent and only backup blocks that have not been previously backed-up. However, this happens automatically and each snapshot contains all the information they require. Just pretend that they are Full Backups because that's how they behave.